# Convert python power (**) to "Pow" in a formula

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column `Input_Equation`, and want to create a new column called
`Output_Equation` by replacing `**` with `Pow`. Sample dataframe with input and expected output is given below. I want `Pow` because my apllication accepts only `Pow` and not any other options like np.power or math.pow.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Input_Equation': [
        '0.06*Log(Sqrt(K / POR))**2 + 0.11',
        '4.96861155787536*(0.917 - POR)**3',
        '3.80241264879314*POR**2'
    ],
    'Output_Equation': [
        '0.06*Pow(Log(Sqrt(K / POR)),2) + 0.11',
        '4.96861155787536*Pow((0.917 - POR),3)',
        '3.80241264879314*Pow(POR,2)'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

How can I acheive this?

Comment: Your outputs are mathematically wrong - when you have `x*y**z` it's `x*Pow(y, z)`, but you have `Pow(x*y, z)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, the expected output is corrected.

Comment: Example of replacing string: data['Input_Equation'].str.replace('**', 'POW')

Comment: It is not just astring replace, I want to replace y**z with Pow(y,z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most generic regex pattern but you can still give it a try :

```
from_to = ["(.+)\*(.+)\*\*(\d+)(.+)?", r"\1*Pow(\2,\3)\4"]

df["Output_Equation"] = df["Input_Equation"].replace(*from_to, regex=True)
```

Output :

```
print(df)
                      Input_Equation                        Output_Equation
0  0.06*Log(Sqrt(K / POR))**2 + 0.11  0.06*Pow(Log(Sqrt(K / POR)),2) + 0.11
1  4.96861155787536*(0.917 - POR)**3  4.96861155787536*Pow((0.917 - POR),3)
2            3.80241264879314*POR**2            3.80241264879314*Pow(POR,2)
```

Comment: thanks, it is working for the example I provided, however it is not working in certain cases, for eg `equation_string = '''PC_IFT1 = PC_IFT1
SWi = (0.4462107*pow(K,-0.284869))
PCe = (pow(10,(log10(sqrt(K / POR))*(0.06*log10(sqrt(K / POR))**2 + 0.11) - log10(sqrt(K / POR)) - 0.97)))
N = (-0.1022338434690877+0.638948201959875*log10(sqrt(K / POR)))
SWi = (0.4462107*pow(K,-0.284869))
PCe = (pow(10,(-2.2893003274291686* pow(log10(sqrt(K / POR)),0.5199731055299214))))
N = (3.80241264879314*POR**2 + 4.96861155787536*(0.917 - POR)**3 + 1/(0.047832147*POR**4 + 1/(POR**2*(POR - 0.917)**3)))'''`

Comment: That's what I said in my answer and your `equation_string` is too complicated IMO to be handled with a naïve regex pattern as the one I provided. You need to think/look for another approach (*maybe mathematics oriented*).